# no internet connection with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, troubleshooting, connection

I installed Windows 7 on my laptop; now it cannot connect to the internet on internet explorer, although it indicates that it is connected to my wireless network.  Plugging in the ethernet cable doesn't give me a connection either.  I am a complete novice and need absolute instructions on how to fix

Comment: What does the network icon say when you hover it in the lower right corner of your screen? What Windows were you using before? Can you reach the page of your router? Can you include the ipconfig information in your question please? Try to right click on the network icon in the lower right corner and click Troubleshoot Problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue that I experienced with Vista at some point. Do you get the "Limited or No Connectivity" message? There is an issue with Vista/Windows 7 and certain old routers. I had an ancient linksys box that caused me all these issues.

In my case the solution was to do the following:

1. Open the device manager
2. Locate your network card, right click and go to Properties
3. Go to the advanced tab
4. Choose the Speed/Duplex Settings item from the list
5. Change the "Auto Negotiate" setting to something else. Try all the different options.

I had to drop mine to 10 Mb Full Duplex. It started working after that.

I wrote about this experience: [Terminally Incoherent - Vista 64 Bit Limited Connectivity (Local Only)](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/06/09/vista-64-bit-limited-connectivity-local-only/).

Comment: It's an awesome article you wrote there which much detail, but it's very unlikely that he will have the same exact cause on both his wired and wireless connection. It's more likely a common configuration issue...

Answer (score -1):

Open a command window by htting windows+r and typing cmd, once there run ipconfig /all -- and post your results here. That should help us diagnose.

Comment: wireless LAN adapter wireless network connection:
Connection-specific DNS suffix: domain_not_set.invalid
description: atheros AR5007 802.11b/g wifiadapter
physical address:

Comment: there's more...I cannot cut & paste so let me know what the critical info is

Comment: @Tami: click on the "edit" button on your question. Add your details to your question. Surround with <pre>..</pre> tags.

Comment: did u ever have internet working for you? is this a fresh install?